# How to iterate over each name in a list for user input?

Tags: python

Am trying to create a BMI calculator and I have a list of people and my goal is to iterate through each person, ask their height weight and store it in a variable. Each time asking them I'm trying to also get it to say their individual names.

```
recipients = ["John", "Dee", "Aleister", "Lilith", "Paul", "Reggy"]

for recipient in recipients:
    height = int(input("What is your height " + str(recipients)))
```

**The output:**

```
What is your height ['John', 'Dee', 'Aleister', 'Lilith', 'Paul', 'Reggy']
```

Comment: You've inadvertently referred to the list instead of the iteration. Change `recipients` to `recipient`. Also, you're overwriting the height, so not really storing the entered value. You could try adding `height` to a list or dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a for loop such as:

```py
recipients = ["John", "Dee", "Aleister", "Lilith", "Paul", "Reggy"]
heights = []
for recipient in recipients:
  heights.append(int(input("What is your height " + recipient)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even use list comprehension:

```
heights = [int(input(r + ', what is your height? ')) for r in recipients]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a for loop

```
recipients = ["John", "Dee", "Aleister", "Lilith", "Paul", "Reggy"]
heights = []
for recipient in recipients:
  heights.append(int(input(f"What is your height {recipient}")))
```

Or use `len()` with list indexing.

```
recipients = ["John", "Dee", "Aleister", "Lilith", "Paul", "Reggy"]
heights = []
for i in range(len(recipients)):
  heights.append(int(input("What is your height " + recipients[i])))
```